# Shrinking navbar when scrolling down, without using Javascript

Tags: html, css

How can get a navbar at the top of the page that shrinks when a visitor scrolls down, and without using Javascipt?

This is done [here](http://www.kriesi.at/themes/enfold/), for example. It would be fine for it to shrink discretely from wide to narrow, rather than shrink continuously as on that site.

(I don't this is a duplicate, because I am specifically asking for this to be done without using Javascript.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is unfortunately outright impossible without JavaScript, as CSS has no way of knowing when the users scrolls down the page.

However, it *is* possible to shrink a header based on cursor position (which is *almost* the same thing) in pure CSS. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17760765/2341603) by Mr Lister.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

i this this will help you

```css
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 position: absolute;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
 display:block;
 min-width:140px;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 background: #2f3036;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
 background: #19c589;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
 display: block;
 float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 background: #19c589;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 0;
 display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
 /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
 ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
 }
 /*Create vertical spacing*/
 li {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
 }
 /*Make all menu links full width*/
 ul li, li a {
  width: 100%;
 }
 /*Display 'show menu' link*/
 .show-menu {
  display:block;
 }
}
```

```html
 <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
  <ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </nav>
```